# Access static variable with custom class name

Tags: php, oop

How can I access static php variable with custom class name. In class c1 method hi() I need to access static variable of its child class. PHP < 5.3

```
class c1{
  function hi(){
    $cn=get_class($this);
    echo $cn::$b; //need echo 5 here, but error
  }
}
class c2 extends c1{
  static public $b=5;
}

$c2=new c2();
$c2->hi();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ReflectionClass`:

```
$cn=get_class($this);
$cl=new ReflectionClass($cn);
echo $cl->getStaticPropertyValue('b');
```

Or `get_class_vars()`:

```
$cn=get_class($this);
$props=get_class_vars($cn);
echo $props['b'];
```

Comment: what about performance? Do I really need to create object just to get value of one property?

Answer (score 1):

One way that popped into my mind is `eval( "return $cn::\$b;" )` but use with care. Eval can create some nasty security holes if the input isn't sanitized correctly.